# What is Vue way to access to data from methods?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, methods

I have the following code:

```
{
  data: function ()  {
    return {
      questions: [],
      sendButtonDisable: false,
    }
  },

  methods: { 
    postQuestionsContent: function () {
      var that = this;
      that.sendButtonDisable = true;
    },
  },
},
```

I need to change `sendButtonDisable` to true when `postQuestionsContent()` is called. I found only one way to do this; with `var that = this;`.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: This should work without `var this = that` (in fact, the way you show it in your example is meaingless, you could leave it out). functions in the `methods:` object will be bound to the current instance. I assume you have left something out in your example - are you doing any AJAX calls and try to change the value inside a callback or something?

Comment: In my case I have my method attached to an event listener on a button. I do not understand vuejs do any more.

Answer (score 89):

Inside methods if you don't have another scope defined inside, you can access your data like that:

```
this.sendButtonDisable = true;
```

but if you have a scope inside the function then in vue is a common usage of a variable called `vm` (stands for **view model**) at the beginning of the function, and then just use it everywhere like:

```
vm.sendButtonDisable = false;
```

An example of `vm` can be seen in the [**Vue official documentation**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) as well.

complete example:

```
data: function ()  {
  return {
     questions: [],
     sendButtonDisable : false
  }
},

methods: { 
  postQuestionsContent : function() {
    // This works here.
    this.sendButtonDisable = true;

    // The view model.
    var vm = this;

    setTimeout(function() {
      // This does not work, you need the outside context view model.
      //this.sendButtonDisable = true;
      
      // This works, since wm refers to your view model.
      vm.sendButtonDisable = true;
    }, 1000); 
  }
}
```

Comment: THIS answer is so useful for vue noobs (voobs?). 
The Vue 2 documentation even makes use of **vm = this** on the following page:
https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers
But it would be easy to oversee this reading through the documentation.

Comment: up for "voobs"!

Comment: also note it will NOT work if we use Arrow function instead of Normal function in `methods`

Comment: Note for people finding this: If you are using lambda notation `this` will not work, so instead use `function(){}`

Answer (score 33):

It depends on how you call your `postQuestionsContent` method (if you call it asynchronously, you might need to `bind` the `this` context).

In most cases, you should be able to access it using `this.$data.YOURPROPNAME`, in your case `this.$data.sendButtonDisable`:

```
data: function ()  {
  return {
     questions: [],
     sendButtonDisable : false
  }

  },

  methods: 
  { 
     postQuestionsContent : function()
     {
        this.$data.sendButtonDisable = true;
     }
  }
```

Comment: Some some reason this does not work. I think the community should review this issue.

Comment: Hi @TheOracle the question and aswer was valid in the realm of vue 0.x versions. 2.x should work normally without `$data`.

Comment: I'm getting this issue using 2.5.17. Might have to report it as a bug, but `$data` works.

Comment: this.$data.something is undefined. Better to use this.something

Comment: Using `Vue-cli 3.x` I can NOT access properties inside `data ()` from e.g. `methods` or `computed` with `this.property` or with `this.$data.property`. Is there another way?

Comment: It is not an issue at all. The correct way of accessing `sendButtonDisable` using `this.$data` is like this: `this.$data[sendButtonDisable]`, because `this.$data`'s array nature. Cheers.

Answer (score 18):

Try this instead

```
...
methods: 
{ 
   postQuestionsContent ()
   {
      this.sendButtonDisable = true;
   }
}
```

Registering your methods in the above manner should resolve the issue.

Comment: Can you explain what's going on here? Why does this work?

Comment: Are you using Nuxtjs? @UmairA.

Comment: @UmairA. From the Vue documentation: `Note that you should <strong>not</strong> use an arrow function to define a method (e.g. plus: () => this.a++). The reason is arrow functions bind the parent context, so this will not be the Vue instance as you expect and this.a will be undefined.` Here: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#methods

Answer (score 0):

I tried both `this.$data.sendButtonDisable` and `vm.sendButtonDisable` and did not work for me.

But I got it working with `outer_this = this`, something like:

```
methods: {
    sendForm(){
        var outer_this;
        
        outer_this = this;
        
        $.ajax({
                url: "email.php",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "text",
                data: {
                    abc: "..."
                },
                success: function(res){
                    if(res){
                        //...
                        
                        outer_this.sendButtonDisable = false;
                    }else{
                        //...
                    }
                }
        });
    }
},
```

Comment: So... you are clamming that just rename "vm" to "outer_this" fix the issue ?